# Git under nushell not using added ssh-key

Tags: git, ssh, nushell

I am having trouble setting up nushell in windows 11 to not always ask me for the password for my ssh-key when I am using git.

I have confirmed that ssh-agent is running used `ssh-add` to add my key and

`ssh-add -l`

shows that the correct key is indeed added.
But whenever I issue a git command that would require ssh, I am asked for my password again.

Any ideas why this might be the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Short Version

```
git config --global core.sshcommand "C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe"
```

##### More Detail

I was able to reproduce this.  It seems that, by default under Nushell:

- In my case, `ssh-add` (and `ssh`) in Nushell is coming from the Windows OpenSSH implementation.  I'm assuming you have the Windows OpenSSH client installed?

  ```
  > which ssh ssh-agent ssh-add 
  ╭───────────┬───────────────────────────────────────────┬──────────╮
  │  command  │                   path                    │   type   │
  ├───────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┤
  │ ssh       │ C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe       │ external │
  │ ssh-agent │ C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh-agent.exe │ external │
  │ ssh-add   │ C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh-add.exe   │ external │
  ╰───────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────╯
  ```
- On the other hand, as far as I can tell, `git` for Windows seems to default to using the Git-bash provided `/usr/bin/ssh`.  This requires that the environment variables are set properly by `/usr/bin/ssh-agent -s` (normally eval'd into Bash or other shell).  Under Git-Bash:

  ```
  $ which ssh ssh-agent ssh-add
  /usr/bin/ssh
  /usr/bin/ssh-agent
  /usr/bin/ssh-add
  ```

Since the Git-bash `/usr/bin/ssh-agent` isn't available under Nushell for Windows, we need to config Git to just use the Windows OpenSSH agent directly.  This can be done ([reference](https://poshsecurity.com/blog/using-the-openssh-client-included-in-windows-10-1809-as-your-gits-ssh-client)) via:

```
git config --global core.sshcommand "C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe"
```

After I did that, `git` under Nushell used my ID to access private GitHub repos.

Comment: Ha! Very nice! And thanks a lot for the in-depth explanation! Kudos!